# Is a rotor balanced at constant angular velocity?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

I have an asymmetrical rotating part.  It vibrates its housing and emits audible noise.  I need to add weights to ensure smooth rotation.  However, I am constrained in which regions I can add material.  I can't exploit rotational symmetry to balance this rotor.

> I define a **rotor** as a **rigid system of particles, each with mass $m_n$ and position $r_n \mathbb\in {R}^3$, rotated about $k$ (the z-axis)**.

What formula describes a rotor that is balanced when spun at constant velocity?  According to Update International, a vendor of rotor balancing systems, [the problem is broken into *static* and *couple* unbalance](http://www.update-intl.com/BalancingBook4.htm).  Here are my interpretations:

## Static balance

When the angular velocity $\omega\neq0$, a net force acts orthogonal to $k$, through the rotor's center of mass.

Static unbalance is resolved by ensuring that the center of mass $C = \dfrac{\sum m_n r_n}{\sum m_n}$ lies along $k$.

$C \times \hat{k} = 0$

Together with the fraction canceled:

$\sum m_n r_n \times \hat{k} = 0$

Rewritten as a scalar system:

$\begin{cases} \sum m_n r_{n,x} = 0 \\ \sum m_n r_{n,y} = 0 \end{cases}$

## Couple unbalance

When the requirements above are met, a pair of equal and opposite net forces act at different points along the axis.  The forces are perpendicular to the axis.

I'm stuck.  How do point-masses give rise to couple unbalance?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. **Couple unbalance is torque.** We want a system where the torque on all particles cancels, or $\sum T_n = 0$.

Torque is defined as $T = r \times F$, where $r$ is the vector from the center of mass to the point where the force is applied.  The center of mass is already constrained to $C \times \hat{k} = 0$; we'll strengthen that constraint to $C = 0$, which leaves this simple equation for the torque on point-mass $n$:

$T_n = r_n \times F_n$

Centripetal force is defined as $F = m r_\perp \omega^2$ where $r_\perp$ excludes the component parallel to $k$.

$r_{n\perp} = r_n \cdot (\hat{i} + \hat{j})$

Combined:

$T_n = r_n \times (m_n r_{n\perp} \omega^2)$

$\sum r_n \times (m_n r_{n\perp} \omega^2) = 0$

Constant $\omega^2$ is divided out:

$\sum r_n \times r_{n\perp} m_n = 0$

Rewritten as a scalar system (note that $r_{n\perp,z}=0$):

$\begin{cases} \sum (r_{n,z} r_{n,y} - 0) m_n = 0
            \\ \sum (0 - r_{n,z} r_{n,x}) m_n = 0
            \\ \sum (r_{n,x} r_{n,y} − r_{n,y} r_{n,x}) m_n = 0 \end{cases}$

Simplify further and remove the last equation (an identity):

$\begin{cases} \sum m_n r_{n,x} r_{n,z} = 0
            \\ \sum m_n r_{n,y} r_{n,z} = 0 \end{cases}$

So together with the condition $C = 0$, we get a system of linear equations that describes **any rotor that is in equilibrium** when spun at constant velocity about $k$:

$\begin{cases} \sum m_n r_{n,x} = 0
            \\ \sum m_n r_{n,y} = 0
            \\ \sum m_n r_{n,z} = 0
            \\ \sum m_n r_{n,x} r_{n,z} = 0
            \\ \sum m_n r_{n,y} r_{n,z} = 0 \end{cases}$

Further reading:

- [Torque - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque)
- [Rigid body dynamics - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics)
- [Example where angular momentum and angular velocity are not parallel - Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79310/24502)
- [On the relation between angular momentum and angular velocity - J. P. Silva and J. M. Tavares](http://sites.isel.ipl.pt/fisica/pedagogia/ajp75(2007)53.pdf)

Comment: Yes. It is possible to balance a rotor so that it will not have a preferred direction under gravity, but that is not sufficient to make sure it is balanced when rotating: that requires there to be a mass balance along axes perpendicular to the axis of rotation. It's nicely described in the [wiki article on wheel balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_balance#The_physics_of_dynamic_balance)