# Does always angular momentum and angular velocity have the same direction?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I was studying how angular momentum is cancelled when it is transferred directly into the origin of the axis of rotation and during the lecture the professor did something and I was pretty confused.

This is the story: in my book, it was stated that the angular velocity, torque and angular momentum always follow the right hand rule and for instance they all head in the same direction. However during the lecture he asserted that the angular momentum was pointing up and the angular velocity the contrary direction. Now I am puzzled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are pozzeld in a lecture, why did you not ask the lecturer during or after the lecture.

Comment: Related, and possibly duplicate of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79294/example-where-angular-momentum-and-angular-velocity-are-not-parallel

Comment: @trula  It's a MOOC, I cannot ask the teacher, there is indeed a comment section, but the professor never answers.

Comment: I have no idea what MOOC is, but in what experiment or situation did the lecturer mention this?

Comment: The lecture was about how is rotational momentum transferred and conserved. To analize this, we were studying the collision between a disk and a bar, the disk collides with the bar at a distance L from the axis of rotation. Then the professor wanted to prove that if the disk hit the bar right in the axis of rotation, it will not rotate. To prove that the angular momentum will be zero, using the parallel axis theorem for angular momentum.  In order to this to be zero, the angular velocity was heading one direction, and the angular momentum another.