# What does the direction of angular momentum signify for a rotating body?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, vectors, rotation

In cases where angular momentum is having a direction different from angular velocity what does it mean physically for the body ? Isn't its direction dependent on the origin ?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29607/cases-in-which-angular-velocity-and-angular-momentum-point-into-same-direction

Comment: It doesn't answer my question